# rsync pattern to include all files of specific patterns and exclude the rest, from all subdirectory tree

Tags: backup, rsync, regex, wildcards

I mean to rsync some files of a subdirectory tree at `dir1`.

I am using

```
[dir1]$ rsync --itemize-changes --recursive --update --times --include-from="rsync_include.dat" --exclude="*" --dry-run ./ remote:~/dir1/
```

The rules are as follow, in this order.

1. Include subdirs `dir11` and `dir12` at level 1.
2. Exclude the rest at level 1.
3. Within `dir11` and `dir12`, include all files `*.cc`, `*.txt` in the subtrees.
4. Within `dir11` and `dir12`, exclude all other files.
5. Within `dir11` and `dir12`, include some specific subtrees (at possibly various levels), with all their contents.

I am not hitting the nail in the head with the proper combinations of single, double and triple asterisks, plus/minus signs, trailing backslashes, and rules order in my `rsync_include.dat`.

**What would the correct contents be?**

Among all I tried, I am posting below the current state of my `rsync_include.dat`.
Among others, it did not match file `classes/src/TEST/classes_test.cc`, which had a later date in `./` than in `remote:~/dir1/`, and therefore I want it to be `rsync`ed.
In this case, I am looking for a pattern that would match that file without me having to enter `+ classes/src/TEST/*.cc`, since there might be other `*.cc` at various depths and branches.

```
+ classes/
+ sanitizers/
- ***/.cproject
+ **/*.cc
+ ***/*.cc
+ **/*.cpp
+ **/*.dat

- */
- **/
```

Comment: It will depend on the contents of your `rsync_include.dat`, so nothing can be said unless you include the contents of that file. You also fail to mention how command you tried does not fulfill your expectations.

Comment: @vanadium - I expanded the OP as requested. What I am asking about is precisely what is the correct contents of my `rsync_include.dat` to achieve my goal.